# g++ -m32 can not find libstdc++ on debian amd64

Tags: c++, debian

I got the following error when compiling a simple hello world program on debian amd64 wheezy(testing) with `g++ -m32`:

> /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/libstdc++.so when searching for -lstdc++
>   /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
>   /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I don't have any problems with `gcc -m32`. I also installed lib32stdc++ package, but it does not seem to work. Thanks.

Comment: I think there may be several 32 bit packages you need to install to get this to work (i.e. more than just lib32stdc++).

Answer (score 20):

Pretty sure you need to install g++-4.6-multilib (it would appear you already have gcc-4.6-multilib).

Answer (score 4):

Try installing `ia32-libs-dev` package.

Comment: Probably also `libc6-dev-i386`

Comment: I did `sudo apt-get install g++-4.6-multilib lib32bz2-dev libc6-dev-i386 lib32z1-dev`